# How do I follow up a video splash page in HTML with a button?

Tags: javascript, html

As a gimmick I am trying to have a short video auto-play when the page loads which should then be followed by an 'Enter' button. I figured out in HTML how to get the video to auto-play, but I'm struggling to switch to a button after it ends.

My code to get the video to auto-play:

```html
<video class="video" width="320" height="240" autoplay>
  <source src="Toei.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

(A CSS class has been added to have it play full screen)

I added a JS event when it finishes

```html
var video = document.querySelector("video");

video.addEventListener("ended", function(){
 video.setAttribute("button", "newButton")
});
```

I get that the setAttribute method will probably not work in order to change the property of the element, but I find it difficult to find how to:

- have an event (video ends) and change the property of the element that ended from 'video' to 'button'

-select this event/property in css to edit the styling.

It is a very simple and short video which should be followed by an 'enter' button in order to go to the actual homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just have a div with the button overlaid (e.g., absolutely positioned) over the video. Defaultly hide it, then in your "movie ended" handler show the div with the button.

Here is the code that should do it. You'll have to make adjustments for exact positioning and styling, and of course to make the button do something/go somewhere.

```js
var video = document.querySelector("video");

video.addEventListener("ended", function() {
 document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "block";
});
```

```css
#myBtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 320px;
  height: 240px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  display: none;
}

#myBtn > button {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<video id="myVid" class="video" width="320" height="240" autoplay>
  <source src="Toei.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<div id="myBtn">
  <button type="button">Go Somewhere</button>
</div>
```

The new `#myBtn` div is absolutely positioned over where the video is located, but `#myBtn` is hidden by default (`display: none`). In the video ended event-handler the `display` style property is changed to `block` so that `#myBtn` becomes visible and covers the video player.

Comment: Yes, but in about 45mins. I'm not at a computer at the moment. :)